# MS SQL Case in Where Clause testing against NULL or Argument

Tags: case, where-clause

I have a query against a UDF where I want to allow the user to pass in either ALL or a specific EType.

If they pass in ALL, I want to accept all ETypes where it is not null.

I have searched thru SO for examples and not seem to meet my particular situation.

Where am I going wrong?

```
Declare
  @company varchar(4),
  @charge_cov bit,
  @EType varchar(8);

  set @company = '123'
  set @charge_cov =1
  set @EType = 'ALL'


  select e.emp_id, 
    dbo.format_emp_number(pd.EN) as EN, 
    dbo.format_emp_number(pd.MEN) as MEN,
    pd.EType
  from dbo.employee_payroll_data(NULL) pd   
    inner join employee e on (e.emp_id=pd.emp_id)
  where  pd.EType = case when @EType='ALL' then pd.EType 
                           else @EType  ) END
  and pd.EType is not null
  and e.emp_number is not null
  and e.charge_cov = 1
  and lc.pr_co_code = @company
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
WHERE (((1 = (CASE WHEN @EType = 'ALL' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)))
OR ((pd.Etype = (CASE WHEN @EType <> 'ALL' THEN @EType ELSE '' END))))
AND pd.Etype IS NOT NULL
```